# How to parse and swap the JavaScript Object using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Actual Output :**

```
 {
   "workbookInformation": {
    ...
  },
  "dashboard1": {
    "auto-hidden": "0",
    "maximized": "1",
    "worksheet": {
      "worksheet8": "APAC",
      "worksheet2": "Freq_SC_Value",
      "worksheet3": "L1 Type Filter",
      "worksheet1": "Pillar Name"
    },
    "class": "dashboard",
    "name": "AnalysisByGeography"
  },
  "dashboard2": {
    ...
  },
  "datasources3": {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Required Output :**

```
      {
  "workbookInformation": {
    ...
  },
  "AnalysisByGeography": {
    "auto-hidden": "0",
    "maximized": "1",
    "worksheet": {
      "APAC": "worksheet8",
      "Freq_SC_Value": "worksheet2",
      "L1 Type Filter": "worksheet3",
      "Pillar Name": "worksheet1"
    },
    "class": "dashboard",
    "name": "AnalysisByGeography"
  },
  "dashboard2": {
    ...
  },
  "datasources3": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried with code which gives key name . i tried "`//jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js`" for swapping the keys. I tried external JS file for reversing the key value pair.

Comment: what do you mean? only change `dashboard1`?

Comment: Could you be more explicit? Did you mean you want "dashboardX" keys to be replaced with their underlying name? Never put INPUT->OUTPUT and expecting people to understand what you want.

Comment: @MasterDJon i want to change the "dashboardx" keys with the "name" values and swap or invert the "worksheetx" with their values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `JSON.stringify(youredata)`. Otherwise maybe u need to split the given data and convert the array with the same function to a json-type.

Comment: You shall have ask questions before answering if you are not sure what the poster intended.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here I wrote for you how to do it, because I don't see more how to explain it. But I strongly suggest, that if you begin in JavaScript, to learn more before asking those type of questions.

Maybe other validations may be needed. Also, I did it only for keys starting with "dashboard", even though I thought it would probably be for all keys having a string plus a number after then and containing an object that has a key "name" in it. If you want to learn, you shall fix that by yourself as you have a pretty strong base here.

Hoping you'll have find learning as I had and still have!

```js
var data = 
{
  "workbookInformation": {
    "a": "..."
  },
  "dashboard1": {
    "auto-hidden": "0",
    "maximized": "1",
    "worksheet": {
      "worksheet8": "APAC",
      "worksheet2": "Freq_SC_Value",
      "worksheet3": "L1 Type Filter",
      "worksheet1": "Pillar Name"
    },
    "class": "dashboard",
    "name": "AnalysisByGeography"
  },
  "dashboard2": {
    "a": "..."
  },
  "datasources3": {
    "a": "..."
  }
}

var isDashboard = new RegExp('dashboard[0-9]+', 'i');
var isWorksheet = new RegExp('worksheet[0-9]+', 'i');
for(var dataKey in data) {
 var innerData = data[dataKey];
 if (typeof(innerData["worksheet"]) == "object") {
  var newWS = {};
  for(var wsKey in innerData["worksheet"]) {
   newWS[innerData["worksheet"][wsKey]] = wsKey;
  }
  innerData["worksheet"] = newWS;
 }

 if (isDashboard.test(dataKey) && innerData['name']) {
  delete data[dataKey];
  dataKey = innerData['name'];
 }
 
 data[dataKey] = innerData;
}

console.log(data);
```